# How to show dropdown in react js?

Tags: reactjs

API:-

```
{
    "No of Players": 2,
    "Players": [
        "A,C",
        "B,D"
    ]
}
```

can i show the C & D in the Dropdown Option i just want to show the dropdown after the comma

Like this:-

```
For A
    <select>
      <option selected>A</option>
      <option >C</option>
    </select> 
For B
    <select>
      <option selected>B</option>
      <option >D</option>
    </select>
```

[image]
in image there is a but i want c & D in dropdown

Comment: You can use `split` method of string

Answer (score 0):

First you need to split the options by delimiter i.e, in your case is comma(,). And then map the options to the array.

```
let obj ={
"No of Players": 2,
"Players": [
    "A,C",
    "B,D"
]
};
obj.PlayersOptions=obj.Players.map((item)=>item.split(','));

{obj.PlayersOptions.map((optionPlayer,index1)=>{
return <select key={index}>
 {optionPlayer.map((opt,index2)=>{
 return <option key={index2}>{opt}</option>
 }}
</select>
}}
```

Note: Please save the optionsArray after split in state as you want and then map them . As I have provided you rough idea.